# java.lang.NullPointerException from SQLite class while accessing database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm new in Android. I'm trying to get data from a database by getDataMain() method. when ı run my application  it gives a java.lang.NullPointerException. I couldn't find where the problem is? Could you help me, please?

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

TextView bakici;
TextView arabaKredisi;
TextView ogrenimKredisi;
TextView tatilKredisi;
TextView elektrik;
TextView su;
TextView internet;
TextView aidat;
TextView kasko;
TextView digerTaksitler;
TextView diger;
TextView maasSelo;
TextView maasHilal;
TextView digerGelirler;
TextView toplamGelir;
TextView toplamHarcama;
TextView eldeKalan;

private final String TAG =  this.getClass().getSimpleName();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "mainFragmentonCreate");

}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maingetirgoster,
            container, false);
    toplamGelir = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textToplamGelir2);
    digerGelirler = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDigerGelirler2);
    toplamHarcama = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textToplamHarcama2);
    diger = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDiger2);
    digerTaksitler = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDigerTaksitler2);
    kasko = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textKaskoSigorta2);
    aidat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAidat2);
    internet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textFaturaInternet2);
    su = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textFaturaSu2);
    elektrik = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textFaturaElektrik2);
    tatilKredisi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTatilKredisi2);
    ogrenimKredisi = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textOgrenimKredisi2);
    arabaKredisi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textKrediAraba2);
    bakici = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textButtonBakici2);
    eldeKalan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textEldeKalan2);
    maasSelo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMaasSelo2);
    maasHilal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textMaasHilal2);

    Context context=getActivity();

    TemporaryDatabase tdb= new TemporaryDatabase(context);
    tdb.open();
    String[] result2= new String[2];
    result2=tdb.getData();
    tdb.close();

    AySonuDatabase adb=new AySonuDatabase(context);
    adb.open();
    String result[]= new String[25];

**line:49** result = adb.getDataMain(Integer.getInteger(result2[0]), result2[1]);
    adb.close();
    bakici.setText(result[2]);
    arabaKredisi.setText(result[3]);
    ogrenimKredisi.setText(result[4]);
    tatilKredisi.setText(result[5]);
    elektrik.setText(result[6]);
    su.setText(result[7]);
    internet.setText(result[8]);
    aidat.setText(result[9]);
    kasko.setText(result[10]);
    digerTaksitler.setText(result[11]);
    diger.setText(result[12]);
    maasSelo.setText(result[13]);
    maasHilal.setText(result[14]);
    digerGelirler.setText(result[15]);
    toplamHarcama.setText(result[16]);
    toplamGelir.setText(result[17]);
    eldeKalan.setText(result[18]);

    Log.i(TAG, "mainFragmentonCreateView");
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

}
```

and here is the database class:

```
public class AySonuDatabase {

public static final String TAG = DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String DB_NAME = "butcedb.sql";
private static String DB_PATH ="/data/data/com.bilge.aysonu/assets/";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DB_TABLE = "harcamalar";

public static final String C_ID = "c_id";// Special for id
public static final String C_YIL = "spinnerYillar";
public static final String C_AY = "spinnerAylar";
public static final String C_BAKICI = "editTextBakici";
public static final String C_KREDIARABA = "editTextKrediAraba";
public static final String C_KREDIOGRENIM = "editTextKrediOgrenim";
public static final String C_KREDITATIL = "editTextKrediTatil";
public static final String C_FATURAELEKTRIK = "editTextFaturaElektrik";
public static final String C_FATURASU = "editTextFaturaSu";
public static final String C_FATURAINTERNET = "editTextFaturaInternet";
public static final String C_AIDAT = "editTextAidat";
public static final String C_KASKOSIGORTA = "editTextKaskoSigorta";

public static final String C_DIGERTAKSITLER = "editTextDigerTaksitler";
public static final String C_DIGER = "editTextDiger";
public static final String C_MAASSELO = "editTextMaasSelo";
public static final String C_MAASHILAL = "editTextMaasHilal";
public static final String C_DIGERGELIRLER = "editTextDigerGelirler";
public static final String C_TOPLAMHARCAMA = "editTextToplamHarcama";
public static final String C_TOPLAMGELIR = "editTextToplamGelir";
public static final String C_ELDEKALAN = "editTextEldeKalan";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE harcamalar (c_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
        "spinnerYillar integer,spinnerAylar TEXT,editTextBakici integer,editTextKrediAraba integer,editTextKrediOgrenim integer,editTextKrediTatil integer," +
        "editTextFaturaElektrik integer,editTextFaturaSu integer,editTextFaturaInternet integer,editTextAidat integer,editTextKaskoSigorta integer," +
        "editTextDigerTaksitler integer,editTextDiger integer,editTextMaasSelo integer,editTextMaasHilal integer,editTextDigerGelirler integer," +
        "editTextToplamHarcama integer,editTextToplamGelir integer, editTextEldeKalan integer);";

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;


public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: " + CREATE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DB_TABLE);
        Log.w(TAG, "onUpdate drop table " + DB_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
public AySonuDatabase(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;

}
public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
    ourDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public  void open() throws NumberFormatException {

    try{
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return ;
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Couldn't open database "+DB_NAME);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close() {

    dbHelper.close();
    ourDatabase.close();
}
public void Entry(int yilsql, String aysql, int bakicisql,
        int krediArabasql, int krediOgrenimsql, int krediTatilsql,
        int faturaElektriksql, int faturaSusql, int faturaInternetsql,
        int aidatsql, int kaskoSigortasql, int digerTaksitlersql, 
        int digersql, int maasSelosql,int maasHilalsql,int digerGelirlersql,
        int toplamHarcamasql,int toplamGelirsql,int eldeKalansql ) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(C_YIL, yilsql);
    cv.put(C_AY, aysql);
    cv.put(C_BAKICI, bakicisql);
    cv.put(C_KREDIARABA, krediArabasql);
    cv.put(C_KREDIOGRENIM, krediOgrenimsql);
    cv.put(C_KREDITATIL, krediTatilsql);
    cv.put(C_FATURAELEKTRIK, faturaElektriksql);
    cv.put(C_FATURASU, faturaSusql);
    cv.put(C_FATURAINTERNET, faturaInternetsql);
    cv.put(C_AIDAT, aidatsql);
    cv.put(C_KASKOSIGORTA, kaskoSigortasql);
    cv.put(C_DIGERTAKSITLER, digerTaksitlersql);
    cv.put(C_DIGER, digersql);
    cv.put(C_MAASSELO,maasSelosql);
    cv.put(C_MAASHILAL, maasHilalsql);
    cv.put(C_DIGERGELIRLER, digerGelirlersql);
    cv.put(C_TOPLAMHARCAMA,toplamHarcamasql);
    cv.put(C_TOPLAMGELIR, toplamGelirsql);
    cv.put(C_ELDEKALAN, eldeKalansql);

    String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{yilsql+"", aysql};
    String entryGirisSQL="SELECT c_id FROM harcamalar WHERE "+C_YIL+"= ? AND "+C_AY+"= ?";
    Cursor cursor=ourDatabase.rawQuery(entryGirisSQL, selectionArgs);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int index=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(C_ID));
    if(cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex(C_ID)))
        ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    else
        ourDatabase.update(DB_TABLE, cv, C_ID+"="+index, null);

    cursor.close();

}
```

protected String[] getDataMain(int yilsql, String aysql){
        String result[]=new String[25];

```
    String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{yilsql+"", aysql};
    String entryHesaplaSQL="SELECT * FROM harcamalar WHERE "+C_YIL+"= ? AND "+C_AY+"= ?";
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.rawQuery(entryHesaplaSQL, selectionArgs);

    if(c.moveToFirst()){

        int i_yil = c.getColumnIndex(C_YIL);
        int i_ay = c.getColumnIndex(C_AY);
        int i_bakici = c.getColumnIndex(C_BAKICI);
        int i_krediaraba = c.getColumnIndex(C_KREDIARABA);
        int i_krediogrenim = c.getColumnIndex(C_KREDIOGRENIM);
        int i_kreditatil = c.getColumnIndex(C_KREDITATIL);
        int i_faturaelektrik = c.getColumnIndex(C_FATURAELEKTRIK);
        int i_faturasu = c.getColumnIndex(C_FATURASU);
        int i_faturainternet = c.getColumnIndex(C_FATURAINTERNET);
        int i_aidat = c.getColumnIndex(C_AIDAT);
        int i_kaskosigorta = c.getColumnIndex(C_KASKOSIGORTA);

        int i_digertaksitler=c.getColumnIndex(C_DIGERTAKSITLER);
        int i_diger=c.getColumnIndex(C_DIGER);
        int i_maasselo=c.getColumnIndex(C_MAASSELO);
        int i_maashilal=c.getColumnIndex(C_MAASHILAL);
        int i_digergelirler=c.getColumnIndex(C_DIGERGELIRLER);
        int i_toplamharcama=c.getColumnIndex(C_TOPLAMHARCAMA);
        int i_toplamgelir=c.getColumnIndex(C_TOPLAMGELIR);
        int i_eldekalan=c.getColumnIndex(C_ELDEKALAN);

        result[0]=c.getString(i_yil);
        result[1]=c.getString(i_ay);
        result[2]=c.getString(i_bakici);
        result[3]=c.getString(i_krediaraba);
        result[4]=c.getString(i_krediogrenim);
        result[5]=c.getString(i_kreditatil);
        result[6]=c.getString(i_faturaelektrik);
        result[7]=c.getString(i_faturasu);
        result[8]=c.getString(i_faturainternet);
        result[9]=c.getString(i_aidat);
        result[10]=c.getString(i_kaskosigorta);
        result[11]=c.getString(i_digertaksitler);
        result[12]=c.getString(i_diger);
        result[13]=c.getString(i_maasselo);
        result[14]=c.getString(i_maashilal);
        result[15]=c.getString(i_digergelirler);
        result[16]=c.getString(i_toplamharcama);
        result[17]=c.getString(i_toplamgelir);
        result[18]=c.getString(i_eldekalan);
        c.close();
        return result;
    } else{

        final String string1= "No data!";
        for(int i=2;i<19;i++)
            result[i]=string1;

        return result; 
    }
```

}

}

here is the whole class of getData() method:

```
    public class TemporaryDatabase {

public static final String TAG = DbHelperTemporary.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String DB_NAME = "aySonuTepmDB.sql";
private static String DB_PATH ="/data/data/com.bilge.aysonu/assets/";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DB_TABLE = "ayyil";

public static final String C_ID = "c_id";// Special for id
public static final String C_YIL = "spinnerYillar";
public static final String C_AY = "spinnerAylar";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE ayyil (c_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
        "spinnerYillar integer,spinnerAylar TEXT);";


private DbHelperTemporary dbHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public static class DbHelperTemporary extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DbHelperTemporary(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: " + CREATE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + DB_TABLE);
        Log.w(TAG, "onUpdate drop table " + DB_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public TemporaryDatabase(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;

}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
    ourDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public  void open() throws NumberFormatException {


        dbHelper = new DbHelperTemporary(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return ;

}

public void close() {

    dbHelper.close();
    ourDatabase.close();
}

public void Entry(int yilsql, String aysql) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(C_YIL, yilsql);
    cv.put(C_AY, aysql);
    ourDatabase.delete(DB_TABLE, null, null);
    ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    cv.clear();
}

public String[] getData() {

    String[] columns = new String[] { C_YIL, C_AY };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,null);
    String[] result = new String[2];

    int i_yil = c.getColumnIndex(C_YIL);
    int i_ay = c.getColumnIndex(C_AY);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        result[0]=c.getString(i_yil);
        result[1]=c.getString(i_ay);
    }
    c.close();
    return result;

}
```

}

here is the exception:

```
I/MainFragment(1838): mainFragmentonCreate
D/AndroidRuntime(1838): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(1838): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3d87908)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1838): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at        com.bilge.aysonu.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):atandroid.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView( Fragment.java:1460)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(1838):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like `tdb.getData()` has returned a null result. I can't see it included, so hard to debug. You should easily be able to figure it out using a debugger though.

Comment: It's preferred to use separate thread for DB operations.

Comment: no, not tdb.getData(), tdb.getDataMain() returns null.

Comment: Looks like getData() returns array with two null values. [null, null]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I was doing wrong. The program throws;

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

at line:49

```
    result = adb.getDataMain(Integer.getInteger(result2[0]), result2[1]);
```

At this line ı wanted to parse string to integer and instead of Integer.parseInt() method I used Integer.getInteger() method. So code is;

```
    result = adb.getDataMain(Integer.parseInt(result2[0]), result2[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

onCreateView is probably too early in the lifecycle to be doing things like accessing the database - I'm guessing that your getActivity() call is returning null.

I'd move the database code to onResume()

Comment: if I remove getMainData() method line from MainFragment, the code is ok. because I think there is a problem with  getMainData()...

Comment: getDataMain() references 'ourDatabase'. Where do you initialize that database?

Answer (score 0):

ok, clearly the value in `result2[0]` is `null` but there is too much non clear things.

1. What is `ourDatabase` in the `getData()` method
2. Is it `ourDatabase` properly opened.
3. What is the result in `c` for this line `Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,null);`

4.Why you first initialize the `result2` array and then assign it - just make it like this: `String[] result2=tdb.getData();`

Comment: 1. ourDatabase is a  SQLiteDatabase                               2.yes it is properly opened.                                         3. c is a cursor and result is a string.I didn't understand what you mean.                                                              4. it can be as you said. but my type is also not wrong.

Comment: what are the results in `c`. When you call `Integer.getInteger(result2[0])` the value in result2[0] is null. This cannot be used as parameter for getInteger.  If the null value is correct, you should handle this case - `if(result2[0] == null) result2[0] = "0";`.